# What is the design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

This was in my exam paper. It says identify the correct design pattern. I wan not able to answer that question. Anyway can anybody knows what is the correct answer?

Consider a scenario where you design and implement your own data structure. New data structure should contain behaviors of a list and it is capable of storing any valid object type. (cats, dogs, box, car, colors etc) 
The users of your custom data structure need to sort the elements in the data structure either in ascending order or descending order. Also they should be able to specify the way the want to sort the elements in the custom data structure. (Eg: Car objects can be sorted by considering the manufacturing year or the price)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Abstract Factory. A regular factory creates concrete objects of one type. An abstract factory creates concrete objects of varying types, depending on the concrete implementation of the factory itself. Its ability to focus on not just concrete objects, but entire families of concrete objects "distinguishes it from other creational patterns, which involve only one kind of product object" (pp51).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Also keep in mind that there are three categories:

1. Creational
2. Structural
3. Behavioral

Just an educated guess:  Creational -> Abstract Factory, Structural -> Flyweight , Behavioral -> Iterator .

Please excuse me if I'm wrong somewhere!

Comment: Agreed, Strategy is appropriaI agree with you @chathurabuddi.  The questions centers around defining custom methods of sorting.  By defining a classic IComparisonStrategy that lets the calling client pass in their preferred sort mechanism this could be implemented easily.